# Why is my celery python module blocked until a task is registered?

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to implement celery in a microservices architecture.

I have ServiceA that need to call tasks on other services X,Y,Z.

In python, when I load my module prior to a task being registered by X, the whole module seems to be blocked.

**Expectation:**
Regardless of queue state, when the python module is loaded I should see 'Starting caller.py.....' followed by a blocked/waiting task

**Actual Result:**
I don't see the print statement. Later, when another service registers a task worker, the whole module then loads...

**ServiceA**

```
from celery import Celery
from time import sleep
from celery.execute import send_task
from retry import retry

# this does not get called until a task is registered from service X
print('Starting caller.py.....')

app = Celery('tasks',
    broker='redis://zredis:6379',
    backend='redis://zredis:6379'
)
    
def register():
    print("HELLLLLLOOOOOOOO REGISTER")

    result = send_task('tasks.getNodeResults', kwargs={})
    node_response = result.get()    
    print('NODE_RESPONSE', node_response)

register()
```

**Question**:
How do I add a job to a queue prior to the worker being registered AND why is this blocking the whole module from loading?

**Observation**:
removing the 'send_task' line and associated code inside the register function unblocks the whole script. Print statements occur etc. etc. Not sure how a statement inside a function could block print statements in the default scope.

**Edit 1**:

I've tried instantiating these multiple ways, 1 as an additional worker, 1 as a direct python module. ( Both with and without pool/concurrency flags )

```
celery -A caller worker --loglevel=CRITICAL --pool=solo --concurrency=1
```

```
python caller
```

Comment: Can you share you the code where you `import` Service A?

Comment: @NivardoAlbuquerque - please see Edit 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with STDOUT and basic python configurations not directly related to celery.

Solution:
The function register() is in fact being called along with the initial print statements. You can see this by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` at varying points.

You can set the follow ENV param:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

What this does:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED
If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to specifying the -u option.
```

Command Line Option:

```
-u
Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.

Note that there is internal buffering in file.readlines() and File Objects (for line in sys.stdin) which is not influenced by this option. To work around this, you will want to use file.readline() inside a while 1: loop.
```